# How to remove duplicate ranges found within array

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to remove duplicate ranges of 3 within an array:

```
let array = [
  "string-1",
  "string-2",
  "string-3",
  "string-4",
  "string-5",
  "string-3",
  "string-4",
  "string-5",
  "string-6",
  "string-7",
  "string-8",
  "string-9",
  "string-10",
  "string-11",
  "string-9",
  "string-10",
  "string-11",
  "string-12"
]
```

The patterns:

```
"string-3",
"string-4",
"string-5"
```

and

```
"string-9",
"string-10",
"string-11"
```

appear twice.

How would I detect and remove them?

Comment: I don't understand this website sometimes. Marked as: "Close - This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."

Tell me where the multiple questions are? Tell me where the multiple problems are? Does my extremely terse question need to be shrunk into a single line of text to avoid the down-voters? Can someone guide me to the Perfect Question?

Comment: Closed with 5 downvotes and no explanation. This is why StackOverflow is dying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func removeDuplicateSequences(from array: [String]) -> [String] {
    var result = array
    var indicesToRemove = Set<Int>()

    // Check for every sequence of three elements in the array
    for i in 0..<result.count - 2 {
        let currentSequence = Array(result[i...i+2])

        // Only proceed if this sequence hasn't been marked for removal
        if !indicesToRemove.contains(i) {
            for j in i+1..<result.count - 2 {
                let nextSequence = Array(result[j...j+2])

                // If a duplicate sequence is found, mark its indices for removal
                if currentSequence == nextSequence {
                    indicesToRemove.insert(j)
                    indicesToRemove.insert(j+1)
                    indicesToRemove.insert(j+2)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Remove elements in reverse order to avoid index out of range errors
    for index in indicesToRemove.sorted(by: >) {
        result.remove(at: index)
    }

    return result
}
```

This fiction meets these requirements. I am not aware of any native version.